# Modx - почему не отображаются превью в Minishop2 при использовании Open Server? Как исправить?

Tags: modx, openserver, minishop2

В админке не отображаются превью у товаров в плагине Minishop2 при использовании Open Server 5.3.5. 
Пробовал запускать сайт на другой версии Open Server (5.2.7) - не помогло. 
Пробовал менять версию PHP (PHP-7.2, PHP-7.1, PHP-5.6) - не помогло.
Пробовал менять версию MySQL (5.7, 8.0) - не помогло.

Пробовал запускать сайт на Laragon - там все нормально.

Я видел в интернете, что помогает выставлять memory_limit не -1, а какое-нибудь другое значение. Я пробовал - не помогло.

Прикладываю скриншоты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такое выводится в core/cache/logs/error.log:

```
[2020-04-26 19:03:31] (ERROR @ D:\1Develop\domains_1\magazin.local\core\components\minishop2\model\minishop2\msproductfile.class.php : 189) [miniShop2] Could not generate thumbnail for "/assets/images/products/3/blue.jpg". Array
(
    [0] => phpThumb() v1.7.15-201902101903 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 229
    [1] => setCacheDirectory() starting with config_cache_directory = "D:/1Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/core/cache/phpthumb/" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1041
    [2] => setting config_cache_directory to $this->realPathSafe(D:\1Develop\domains_1\magazin.local\core\cache\phpthumb) = "D:\1Develop\domains_1\magazin.local\core\cache\phpthumb" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1069
    [3] => setSourceFilename(D:\1Develop\domains_1\magazin.local\ms_686F.tmp) set $this->sourceFilename to "D:\1Develop\domains_1\magazin.local\ms_686F.tmp" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 294
    [4] => $AvailableImageOutputFormats = array(text;ico;bmp;wbmp;gif;png;jpeg;webp) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1005
    [5] => $this->thumbnailFormat set to $this->config_output_format "jpeg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1016
    [6] => $this->thumbnailFormat set to $this->f "jpeg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1023
    [7] => $this->thumbnailQuality set to "90" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1033
    [8] => $this->sourceFilename set to "D:Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/ms_686F.tmp" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 926
    [9] => phpThumb() v1.7.15-201902101903
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net

Error messages disabled.

edit phpThumb.config.php and (temporarily) set
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['disable_debug'] = false;
to view the details of this error in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 4188
    [10] => SetCacheFilename() _src set from md5($this->sourceFilename) "D:Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/ms_686F.tmp" = "617585d48fbb997005de9201620ea286" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3582
    [11] => SetCacheFilename() _par set from md5(_bg000000_farC_zc1_h90_w120_dpi150_q90) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3615
    [12] => starting ExtractEXIFgetImageSize() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3380
    [13] => getimagesize(D:Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/ms_686F.tmp) says image is x in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3390
    [14] => getimagesize("D:Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/ms_686F.tmp") failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3419
    [15] => $this->useRawIMoutput=false because "bg" is set in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1625
    [16] => $this->useRawIMoutput=false after checking $UnAllowedParameters in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1631
    [17] => ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() aborting because ImageMagickCommandlineBase() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2358
    [18] => ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3426
    [19] => SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() starting with ""x"" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3359
    [20] => SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() setting w="120", h="90" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3375
    [21] => EXIF thumbnail extraction: (size=0; type=""; 0x0) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3483
    [22] => starting SourceImageToGD() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3741
    [23] => starting ImageCreateFromFilename(D:Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/ms_686F.tmp) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3656
    [24] => empty $filename or getimagesize(D:Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/ms_686F.tmp) failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3705
    [25] => Populating $rawimagedata in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3713
    [26] => cannot fopen(D:Develop/domains_1/magazin.local/ms_686F.tmp) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3724
    [27] => Not using EXIF thumbnail data because $this->exif_thumbnail_data is empty in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3813
    [28] => $this->gdimg_source is still empty in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3865
    [29] => ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3867
    [30] => phpThumb() v1.7.15-201902101903
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net

Error messages disabled.

edit phpThumb.config.php and (temporarily) set
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['disable_debug'] = false;
to view the details of this error in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 4188
    [31] => SourceImageToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 374
)

[2020-04-26 19:03:31] (ERROR @ D:\1Develop\domains_1\magazin.local\core\xpdo\om\xpdoobject.class.php : 240) Error 42000 executing statement: 
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC LIMIT 1' at line 1
)
```

Comment: В "Инструментах разработчика", кроме консоли и прочего, есть закладка "Network". Если перейти в неё, поставить фильтр *Img* и перезапустить страницу, то что-либо подозрительное обнаружите?

Comment: @Deonis, я добавил скриншот, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема, но уже не помню детали, это точно связано с библиотекой phpThumb.
Попробуйте поковыряться в ее настройках, те, что в системных переменных, измените дефолтные на свои,убедитесь,что библиотека свежая, хватает прав и пространства для записи и т.п.